# Sharing page content between sites

Tags: publishing-site, navigation

I am using SharePoint 2007 Enterprise + Publishing portal template + Windows Server 2008. In the default web site of publishing portal, there is a "Press Release" subsite. I have create another site called "Subsite1", which is a subsite of "Press Release".

Here is the hierarchy:

```
Root site
  --- Press Release (child of root site)
     --- Subsite1 (child of press release site)
```

Now, "Press Release" is in the global top navigation bar. "Subsite1" is in the left hand navigation bar when "Press Release" is selected from the global top navigation bar.

I want to display the same page content in the central area when the user clicks "Press Release" in the global top navigation bar, and when the user clicks "Subsite1" in the left hand navigation bar of the "Press Release" site. Any ideas how to implement?

Comment: @George2: You don't need to give your name as it's already shown on the question. Also you don't need to write "thanks" as thanks is given by upvoting and accepting answers. Just a tip ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use Reusable Content.

**100% out of the box**

Insert an entry in your Reusable Content list and insert/reference it from a Rich Html field control on both pages (it's your responsibility to place the Rich Html field controls in the right position on your Page Layout or Master Page).

You have the option to specify whether you want the content on the pages to automatically update when the item in the Reusable Content list is updated or you can choose to have it "disconnected".

Comment: Cool Jaap! Question answered!

Comment: Be aware that reusable content (AFAIR) still isnt supported if you use RAD editor for sharepoint. So if you use that, this could be a problem

Answer (score 3):

Another option would be doing a redirect to Subsite1 if someone hits the Press Release page. 
By this way you don't have to manage two pages with the same content.

The redirect could be done by a simple web part you place on the Press Release page.

Answer (score 2):

The **default.aspx** page that you see in the **Press Release** site and **subsite1** are totally different.
There is no out of the box way to get the same content in both the page,There are few options you can try, to make it similar.

1. Have the same master page in both the sub site.
2. delete the Default.aspx and create the page based on same layout in both the site.
3. By the above steps you will be able to get a similar branding in the both the pages.
4. When it comes to Content in the page, you will have to paste the same content in the subsite1 page.
5. You can use a Web Part and Place the Web part in the both the pages.

Comment: 1. I have a question about step 1, how to make two sites share the same master page? 2. about step 2, what do you mean delete? Delete from file system or some management interface?

Comment: If you navigate to the site Settings you will have a Link called Master Page under the look and Feel, you can use that to set the master page for the site.
2. You can use SPD to delete that, reason why I want you to delete the page is that default page of these sites might be based on the different layout pages.